# How to display div after submit the form from popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display ("block") the div(id="myWrapperMain") after when I clicked on button (type="submit" id="log") on my form in the popup, but this div displayed just for 1 second, after that it disappeared. What I have to add in my code to keep my div opened in my page ?

Thanks for any help of anyone how can give me any response. 
Basia

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<body>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" style="display:block">Run workflow  from Pronghorn</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form id="modal-wrapper" action="/os_copy/authentification.php">
            <input type="text" size="15" placeholder="user" name="user" />
            <input type="password" size="15" placeholder="pwd" name="pwd" />
            <button type="submit" id="log" name="logSub" value="submit"> Login </button>
        </form>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>

<div class="main-wrapper" id="myWrapperMain" style="display:none">
    <h1>Table 1</h1>
        <div class="table-wrapper" >
            <table class="demo-table" >
            <caption class="title">Executing workflow</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>WORKFLOW </th>
                    <th>DEVICE NAME </th>
                    <th>FILE NAME </th> 
                    <th>SIZE </th>  
                    <th>URL </th>
                    <th>CLEANNING </th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
<script>
var wrapperMain  = document.getElementById('myWrapperMain');
var btnLog       = document.getElementById("log");
var btnAuth      = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btnLog.onclick   = function() {
    btnAuth.style.display = "none";
    wrapperMain.style.display = "block";
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: when you submit a form it posts back your entire page to the server, and then downloads a new copy from the server (i.e. the server provides new data in response to your postback request). So basically, the copy of your page which was running (which includes any JavaScript being run) is destroyed, and a brand new copy is downloaded. This is the normal behaviour for a HTML form ever since they were invented, and so obviously your div only appears for a moment because the page you added it is then destroyed and replaced with a new copy.

Comment: If you want to make your modal appear after the form is submitted you could either a) Use JavaScript to stop the normal postback behaviour of the form, and instead submit the form data to the server via an AJAX request (i.e. a HTTP request launched within the page via script, and which doesn't refresh the entire page), and then when you get the response back from the server you know it's time to display the div. Or, b) change your server-side code so that when it returns the brand new page after the postback, the HTML is in a state whereby the required div is already being shown.